# AVR putting UART input into a circular buffer and getting them back again

Tags: c, avr, uart

I'm having trouble getting input from a UART into a circular buffer and then out again.  The circular buffer code is from http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LightweightRingBuff.h, which I've used successfully before, but not within an interrupt service.  In this project I was able to get things working by polling the UART, but I realize now that I need to use interrupts.  So, I rejiggered things to what I thought would work as an interrupt service, but I get nothing useful from `uart_getchar()`.  With debugging `printf()s` I found that it gets called twice, but never actually returns.

Here's the minimal working example:

```
/* A proof of concept implementation of a command line on an AVR */
/*
 * Compile/build/program with:
 * avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -std=gnu99 -mmcu=atmega164p -o linetest.elf linetest.c
 * avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex linetest.elf linetest.hex
 * avrdude -c usbtiny -p m164p -U flash:w:linetest.hex:i
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <util/atomic.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#define UART_BAUD 9600
#define BAUDRATE F_CPU/16/BAUD-1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 80

int uart_putchar(char, FILE *);
int uart_getchar(FILE *);
void uart_init(unsigned int);

typedef uint8_t rbuf_data_t;
typedef uint8_t rbuf_count_t;

typedef struct {
    rbuf_data_t buffer[80];
    rbuf_data_t *in;
    rbuf_data_t *out;
    rbuf_count_t    count;
} rbuf_t;

void rbuf_init(rbuf_t* const);
rbuf_count_t rbuf_getcount(rbuf_t* const);
bool rbuf_isempty(rbuf_t*);
void rbuf_insert(rbuf_t* const, const rbuf_data_t);
rbuf_data_t rbuf_remove(rbuf_t* const);

rbuf_t  rbuf;
char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
FILE uart_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    sei();
    uart_init(UART_BAUD);
    printf_P(PSTR("\n\nHello World!\nType a line and see it printed back.\n"));
    for (;;) {
        printf_P(PSTR("> "));
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line) - 1, stdin) == NULL) {
            putchar('\n');
            continue;
        }

        if (strlen(line) <= 1) continue;
        printf_P(PSTR("\n- "));

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
            putchar(line[i]);
            _delay_ms(300);
        }
        printf_P(PSTR("\n"));
    }
    printf_P(PSTR("\nSomething barfed.\n"));
    return 0;
}


void rbuf_init(rbuf_t* const buffer)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        buffer->in    = buffer->buffer;
        buffer->out   = buffer->buffer;
        buffer->count = 0;
    }
    return;
}


rbuf_count_t rbuf_getcount(rbuf_t* const buffer)
{
    rbuf_count_t count;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        count = buffer->count;
    }
    return count;
}


bool rbuf_isempty(rbuf_t* buffer)
{
    return (rbuf_getcount(buffer) == 0);
}


void rbuf_insert(rbuf_t* const buffer, const rbuf_data_t data)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        if ((buffer->in) == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer)])
            return;
        *buffer->in = data;
        ++buffer->in;
        buffer->count++;
    }
    return;
}


rbuf_data_t rbuf_remove(rbuf_t* const buffer)
{
    rbuf_data_t data;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        data = *buffer->out;
        if (++buffer->out == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer)])
            buffer->out = buffer->buffer;
        buffer->count--;
    }
    return data;
}


ISR (USART0_RX_vect)
{
    uint8_t c;

//  if (UCSR0A & _BV(FE0))
//      return;
//  if (UCSR0A & _BV(DOR0))
//      return;
    c = UDR0;
    rbuf_insert(&rbuf, (rbuf_data_t) c);

    return;
}


/*
 * Receive a character from the UART Rx.
 *
 */
int uart_getchar(FILE *stream)
{
    uint8_t c;

    while (rbuf_isempty(&rbuf)); /* block until something's there */

    c = rbuf_remove(&rbuf);

    /* this executes twice then nothing more seen */
    printf_P(PSTR("+%c"), c);
    return c;
}


/*
 * Initialize the UART to baud/bps, tx/rx, 8N1.
 */
void uart_init(unsigned int baud)
{
    rbuf_init(&rbuf);
    stdout = stdin = &uart_str;

#if F_CPU < 2000000UL && defined(U2X)
    UCSR0A = _BV(U2X);  /* improve baud rate error by using 2x clk */
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (8UL * baud)) - 1;
#else
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (16UL * baud)) - 1;
#endif
    /* Clear error flags, MODbus protocol: */
    UCSR0A=0x00;
    /* Enable TX, RX, and RX interrupt */
    UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0);

    return;
}


/*
 * Send character c down the UART Tx, wait until tx holding register
 * is empty.
 */
int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    if (c == '\a') {
        fputs("*ring*\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
        uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noted some issues in your code when working with the ring buffer.

First of all, in `rbuf_insert`:

```
        if ((buffer->in) == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer)])
```

and the same in `rbuf_remove`:

```
        if (++buffer->out == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer)])
```

Note, `sizeof` is used on the variable named `buffer`, which is the function parameter `rbuf_t* const buffer`. It is a pointer, therefore sizeof(buffer) will be 2.

Probably you want to use `&buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer->buffer)])`

Second. In `rbuf_insert`:

```
        if ((buffer->in) == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer)])
            return;
```

After `buffer->in` reaches the top (assuming you'll fix that `sizeof`), the function will always return and no new data can be placed in the buffer, because buffer->in never wrapped around.

Probably you want something like that:

```
void rbuf_insert(rbuf_t* const buffer, const rbuf_data_t data)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        if (buffer->count == sizeof(buffer->buffer)) // if the buffer is full..
            return;
        if ((buffer->in) == &buffer->buffer[sizeof(buffer->buffer)]) // if the pointer at the top
            buffer->in = buffer->buffer; // wrap around
        *buffer->in = data;
        ++buffer->in;
        buffer->count++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think this happened as a result of coding while tired.  I ultimately figured it out after someone questioned the rbuf code.  One of my mistakes was in borrowing the rbuf code from an earlier project.  In that one, I modified the code for some reason I forget.  It worked there, but none of it was called in an interrupt.  Going back to the original code (link at top) I found things worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version of what I've been fiddling with.  The objective of all this is to get a command-line interface through an RS232 serial port on an AVR.  I'm experimenting with things that resemble POTS modems in operation.

```
/* A proof of concept implementation of a command line on an AVR */
/*
 * Compile/build/program with:
 * avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -std=gnu99 -mmcu=atmega164p -o linetest.elf linetest.c
 * avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex linetest.elf linetest.hex
 * avrdude -c usbtiny -p m164p -U flash:w:linetest.hex:i
 *
 */

#include <util/atomic.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define UART_BAUD 9600
#define BAUDRATE F_CPU/16/BAUD-1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 80

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int uart_putchar(char, FILE *);
int uart_getchar(FILE *);
void uart_init(unsigned int);

typedef uint8_t rbuf_data_t;
typedef uint8_t rbuf_count_t;

typedef struct {
    rbuf_data_t buffer[80];
    rbuf_data_t *in;
    rbuf_data_t *out;
    rbuf_count_t    count;
} rbuf_t;

void rbuf_init(rbuf_t *);
rbuf_count_t rbuf_getcount(rbuf_t *);
bool rbuf_isempty(rbuf_t *);
void rbuf_insert(rbuf_t *, const rbuf_data_t);
rbuf_data_t rbuf_remove(rbuf_t *);

volatile bool command;      /* Command line active? */
volatile bool quit_early;   /* Abort processing. */

rbuf_t  rbuf;
char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
FILE uart_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char c;

    sei();
    uart_init(UART_BAUD);

    printf_P(PSTR("\n\nHello World!\nType a line and see it printed back.\n"));
    for (;;) {

        command = TRUE;
        printf_P(PSTR("> "));

        c = fgetc(stdin);
        i = 0;
        while (i < sizeof(line)) {
            if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                line[i] = 0;
                break;
            }

            line[i] = c;
            i++;
            printf("%c", c);
            c = fgetc(stdin);
        }
        command = FALSE;

        printf_P(PSTR("\n- "));

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
            if (quit_early) {
                printf_P(PSTR(" ABORT"));
                break;
            }
            putchar(line[i]);
            _delay_ms(300);
        }
        printf_P(PSTR("\n"));
        quit_early = FALSE;
    }
    printf_P(PSTR("\nSomething barfed.\n"));
    return 0;
}


void rbuf_init(rbuf_t* const buffer)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        buffer->in    = buffer->buffer;
        buffer->out   = buffer->buffer;
        buffer->count = 0;
    }
    return;
}


rbuf_count_t rbuf_getcount(rbuf_t* const buffer)
{
    rbuf_count_t count;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        count = buffer->count;
    }
    return count;
}


bool rbuf_isempty(rbuf_t* buffer)
{
    return (rbuf_getcount(buffer) == 0);
}


void rbuf_insert(rbuf_t* const buffer, const rbuf_data_t data)
{
    *buffer->in = data;

    if (++buffer->in == &buffer->buffer[BUFFER_SIZE])
        buffer->in = buffer->buffer;

    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        buffer->count++;
    }
}


rbuf_data_t rbuf_remove(rbuf_t* const buffer)
 {
    rbuf_data_t data = *buffer->out;

    if (++buffer->out == &buffer->buffer[BUFFER_SIZE])
        buffer->out = buffer->buffer;

    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        buffer->count--;
    }

    return data;
}


ISR (USART0_RX_vect)
{
    uint8_t c;


    /* Maybe put these in the else below? */
//  if (UCSR0A & _BV(FE0))
//      return;
//  if (UCSR0A & _BV(DOR0))
//      return;

    c = UDR0;

    /* If command line is active, store the character. */
    if (command)
        rbuf_insert(&rbuf, (rbuf_data_t) c);
    else {  /* Otherwise check to see if we need to abort. */
        if (c == 0x03)
            quit_early = TRUE;
    }

    return;
}


/*
 * Receive a character from the UART Rx.
 *
 */
int uart_getchar(FILE *stream)
{
    uint8_t c;

    while (rbuf_isempty(&rbuf)); /* block until something's there */
    c = rbuf_remove(&rbuf);
    return c;
}


/*
 * Initialize the UART to baud/bps, tx/rx, 8N1.
 */
void uart_init(unsigned int baud)
{
    rbuf_init(&rbuf);

#if F_CPU < 2000000UL && defined(U2X)
    UCSR0A = _BV(U2X);  /* improve baud rate error by using 2x clk */
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (8UL * baud)) - 1;
#else
    UBRR0L = (F_CPU / (16UL * baud)) - 1;
#endif
    /* Clear error flags, MODbus protocol: */
    UCSR0A=0x00;
    /* Enable TX, RX, and RX interrupt */
    UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0);

    stdout = stdin = &uart_str;

    return;
}


/*
 * Send character c down the UART Tx, wait until tx holding register
 * is empty.
 */
int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    if (c == '\a') {
        fputs("*ring*\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
        uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;

    return 0;
}
```